# With openpsoe,how to output image without keypoints and linking lines in it?

Tags: openpose

I have tried all kinds of command line options compositions,but none of them worked as expected,so is that possible?How to do?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the flag `-render_pose 0`

(Directly from the instructions:
https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/demo_overview.md)

Comment: Thanks,this will turn it off completely,so pose related info will miss in json also.What I want is keeping pose info in json but 'removing' points and linking lines in image

Comment: That should not be the case, ``render_pose 0`` will just disable the blending of keypoints in the image, it has nothing to do with the ``write_keypoint_json`` flag. If it has, then I have a bug in the code. Could you add the exact command you use? It should be something like ``--render_pose 0 --write_keypoint_json output_folder``. Also, as you don't want to render the keypoints, you might also remove the output display for small speed up: ``--render_pose 0 --no_display --write_keypoint_json output_folder``.

Comment: './openpose.bin --no_display --render_pose 0 --write_images /home/alex/debug --write_keypoint_json /home/alex/debug --video /home/alex/video.mp4'    gives me error 'Error:
In order to save the rendered frames (`write_images` or `write_video`), you must set `render_output` to true.'

Comment: I need pose info in just json without keypoints and linking lines in images

Comment: That was fixed around a month ago, download the latest version, But even in that version, ``openpose.bin --no_display --render_pose 0 --write_keypoint_json /home/alex/debug`` will work (if you don't need the images).